# How can the panel method be used to find drag and lift if it is for invicid flow?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, drag, viscosity, lift

If simple CFD softwear like XFoil and OpenVSP use the panel method to find an estimate of the drags and lifts/pressure distributions. How do they find drag and lift if the panel method works based on invicid flow? I thought that there can be no drag or lift created in a complete invicid flow which i think i do understand. (I am awear its obvious the panel method cant calculate purley from itself the skin friction) But it is not at all obvious to me regading any form/induced drag

Im at university but we mostly just use the softwear/equations, but i recetly take the time to actually try understand the working/derivations so apologies theres something obvious missed.

Comment: Most Aerospace Engineers would not consider XFoil and VSPAERO to be 'CFD'.  Even though they are certainly computer programs used to study fluid dynamics.  These are 'panel codes' -- which use what mathematicians call boundary element methods to solve the potential equation using only a boundary discretization.  CFD usually implies a finite difference or finite volume method applied to either the Euler or Navier Stokes equations applied to a volume discretization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Questions about OpenVSP are best directed to the [OpenVSP Google Group](https://groups.google.com/g/openvsp).  [Aviation SE](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/) is also a great place to ask aerodynamics questions.

The potential flow parts of XFoil and VSPAERO can only calculate inviscid flow.

[XFoil](https://web.mit.edu/drela/Public/web/xfoil/) is a 2D code, so its inviscid mode can not calculate any drag.

VSPAERO is a 3D code, so its inviscid capability can estimate the induced drag.

Both tools have (very different) ways of estimating viscous sources of drag.

Remember, all models are wrong, some models are useful.

XFoil uses an integral boundary layer model.  This means that the boundary layer equations have been rearranged and manipulated into an integral.  The boundary layer equations are parabolic, which means that information only flows in one direction and a space marching algorithm can be used.  One of the thin [boundary layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_layer) assumptions is that the pressure 'across' the boundary layer is constant.  So, the 'inviscid' pressure is used as the pressure on the outside of the boundary layer.  Integration starts at the stagnation point and proceeds to the trailing edge.

XFoil has different modes that couple the inviscid and viscous solution in different ways.  In the fully coupled mode, I believe the boundary layer's momentum thickness is used to perturb the inviscid airfoil's shape (via a transpiration boundary condition) to iteratively get the pressure distribution to better match what the real flow would see.

XFoil was developed for relatively low Reynolds numbers, so it works best in those situations.  It has models for laminar separation bubbles, laminar to turbulent transition, and other complex phenomena.  It is a very good 2D airfoil code whose solutions are widely used.

VSPAERO's viscous drag estimate is far more primitive than XFoil's.  It uses some empirical models to estimate the local skin friction drag.  For wings, it uses models of airfoil drag coefficient as a function of Reynolds Number, Mach Number, lift coefficient, and thickness to chord ratio.  For bodies, it uses a simple form factor and Reynolds number lookup for skin friction coefficient.

VSPAERO's estimate is better than nothing, but not much.  In particular, a panel code model will leave out lots of details (landing gear and other sometimes important chunks of the airframe.  Protuberances, antennae, scoops and nozzles for cooling, hinge gaps, surface roughness, etc.)  These all contribute to drag and are all left out of the model.  So when VSPAERO gives you an unrealistic L/D, don't forget all the D that it doesn't know about.

I expect some upgrades to VSPAERO's drag models to be in place by H2 2024 that will allow the user to specify arbitrary additional drag terms to be added to the aircraft -- and also for the user to specify airfoil drag models to be used for lifting surfaces.

For now, I typically recommend users ignore VSPAERO's viscous drag term and instead use OpenVSP's parasite drag buildup tool (or their own tool) to estimate the friction drag of the aircraft.  The main exception to this is if you are using the unsteady propeller/rotor capabilities of VSPAERO, in that case, the airfoil drag model is very useful at estimating the parasite power for the prop/rotor.

Comment: This was very insightfull, when you say xfloil couples the invicid and vicid solutions, what actual information can the invicid solution give? Am i correct in saying that in a purley invicid flow there cant be any drag or lift? Thanks

Comment: @Rob McDonald "XFoil was developed for relatively low Reynolds numbers, so it works best in those situations." I think it's more accurate to say that XFoil is better than other methods for low Reynolds numbers. At higher Reynolds numbers, the boundary layers are thinner and even simpler models can give excellent results, but XFoil is probably never worse than they are.

Comment: @George kirby Purely inviscid flow models can compute lift (sometimes very accurately) as long as they allow for some circulation to be present (like the distributed vorticity on XFoil's panels). I will try to write a more complete answer when I have time, but suggest you read about the Kutta condition in the meantime. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kutta_condition

Comment: @Georgekirby The inviscid part of XFoil calculates the pressure distribution on the outside of the boundary layer.  The boundary layer computes the displacement thickness that modifies the airfoil's shape.  An inviscid 2D airfoil panel code can compute the airfoil's lift and moment -- but the purely inviscid drag will be zero.

Comment: @D.Halsey fair point.  However, at high Re, we often care about higher Mach effects.  Someone interested in high Re airfoil design is likely working on a transonic transport or similar application where XFoil's limitations in that axis would come into play.

Comment: @Rob McDonald Panel codes assume incompressible flow and would never be used for transonic flows.

Comment: @D.Halsey That is my point.  Few people are looking at Re of 10 to 100e6 without looking at transonic flow.

Comment: @Rob McDonald When I mentioned "higher Reynolds numbers", I meant high enough to avoid extensive laminar separation - maybe 2e6 or 3e6. For Re values greater than that, I believe very simple interaction schemes can often be adequate. And not just for panel codes. For compressible potential flow or Euler solvers also.

Comment: @D.Halsey  We're on the same page.  Ask anyone in fluids what 'low speed' and 'high speed' flows are and you'll dramatically different answers depending on what flow regime they consider 'normal'.  For some, 'low' Re is only < 100.